# How to install SpatiaLite 3 on 12.04?

Tags: software-installation, sqlite

I'm having some problems to install SpatiaLite 3 on Ubuntu 12.04, those are the steps to I did:

1) `sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev  libgeos-dev`

2) `libspatialite-3.0.0-stable$ ./configure`

Result: `configure: error: cannot find proj_api.h, bailing out`

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking stdio.h usability... yes
checking stdio.h presence... yes
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for memory.h... (cached) yes
checking math.h usability... yes
checking math.h presence... yes
checking for math.h... yes
checking float.h usability... yes
checking float.h presence... yes
checking for float.h... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
checking stddef.h usability... yes
checking stddef.h presence... yes
checking for stddef.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking sqlite3.h usability... yes
checking sqlite3.h presence... yes
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking sqlite3ext.h usability... yes
checking sqlite3ext.h presence... yes
checking for sqlite3ext.h... yes
checking for g++... no
checking for c++... no
checking for gpp... no
checking for aCC... no
checking for CC... no
checking for cxx... no
checking for cc++... no
checking for cl.exe... no
checking for FCC... no
checking for KCC... no
checking for RCC... no
checking for xlC_r... no
checking for xlC... no
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... no
checking whether g++ accepts -g... no
checking dependency style of g++... none
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to i686-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... dlltool
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for off_t... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking whether struct tm is in sys/time.h or time.h... time.h
checking for working volatile... yes
checking whether lstat correctly handles trailing slash... yes
checking whether lstat accepts an empty string... no
checking whether lstat correctly handles trailing slash... (cached) yes
checking for working memcmp... yes
checking whether stat accepts an empty string... no
checking for strftime... yes
checking for memset... yes
checking for sqrt... no
checking for strcasecmp... yes
checking for strerror... yes
checking for strncasecmp... yes
checking for strstr... yes
checking for fdatasync... yes
checking for ftruncate... yes
checking for getcwd... yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for localtime_r... yes
checking for memmove... yes
checking for strerror... (cached) yes
checking for sqlite3_prepare_v2 in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for sqlite3_rtree_geometry_callback in -lsqlite3... yes
checking proj_api.h usability... no
checking proj_api.h presence... no
checking for proj_api.h... no
configure: error: cannot find proj_api.h, bailing out
```

Answer (score 2):

Install [libproj-dev [image: Install libproj-dev]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libproj-dev); it will solve the problem.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libproj-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the geos-devel package installed?

First google result for "configure: error: cannot find proj_api.h, bailing out ubuntu"

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/spatialite-users/_EIrlEKPx00/Rx6Fn4tzkzUJ

Comment: sudo apt-get install geos-devel
E: Unable to locate package geos-devel

Comment: Posting in that usergroup may be more beneficial for such a specific package vs such a general user group here.